# Eclipse:I cannot import javax.json (or javax.json.stream)

Tags: java, maven, gson, json-api

Trying to use GSON and JSON-api. No issues with importing GSON into my code.

Getting error ("cannot find symbol" message in Eclipse compiler) when importing JSON-api.

The end result is that I want to use "JsonParser" which according to an Oracle page (click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html) for link) is inside javax.json.

Here's a snippet of my java code:

```
package com.myorg.core.impl.view.tools;

import com.google.gson.Gson; //no error

import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;
import javax.jcr.Session;
import javax.json; // error
//also tried import javax.json.stream same results.
```

I have the following lines in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- I also tried version 1.0. same result -->
```

In both dependencies, I can see the jar files in my Eclipse .m2 repository

```
myuser@myusers-MacBook-Pro : repository
=> find ~/.m2 -iname "*gson*" -type f
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.7/gson-2.7.jar
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.7/gson-2.7.jar.lastUpdated
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.7/gson-2.7.jar.sha1
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.7/gson-2.7.pom
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.7/gson-2.7.pom.lastUpdated
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.7/gson-2.7.pom.sha1
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson-parent/2.7/gson-parent-2.7.pom
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson-parent/2.7/gson-parent-2.7.pom.lastUpdated
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson-parent/2.7/gson-parent-2.7.pom.sha1
11:54:03 Thu Nov 16
myuser@myusers-MacBook-Pro : repository
=> find ~/.m2 -iname "*json-api*" -type f
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/javax/json/javax.json-api/1.1.2/javax.json-api-1.1.2.jar
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/javax/json/javax.json-api/1.1.2/javax.json-api-1.1.2.jar.lastUpdated
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/javax/json/javax.json-api/1.1.2/javax.json-api-1.1.2.jar.sha1
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/javax/json/javax.json-api/1.1.2/javax.json-api-1.1.2.pom
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/javax/json/javax.json-api/1.1.2/javax.json-api-1.1.2.pom.lastUpdated
/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/javax/json/javax.json-api/1.1.2/javax.json-api-1.1.2.pom.sha1
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly about your import

```
import javax.json; // error, sure it will be an error
```

Above should tell you something like

> Only a type can be imported. javax.json resolves to a package

So import type or **types** with a wildcard:

```
import javax.json.*;
import javax.json.stream.*;
```

or just the `JsonParser`

```
import javax.json.stream.JsonParser;
```

> The end result is that I want to use "JsonParser"

You have dependency for `javax.json-api` in your pom.

It is just an `API` having  only

```
package javax.json.stream;

interface JsonParser { ...
```

On the other hand `GSON` does not implement that but has its own

```
package com.google.gson;

public final class JsonParser // not implementing above mentioned
```

I am not an expert with all the `JSON` libraries available but at a very quick glance could not find any `JsonParser` implementations strictly implementing that interface in that package.

Maybe you manage with `com.google.gson.JsonParser` only?